# How can I get Primary Key in Yii 2 crud generator template

Tags: yii2

I use gii code generator and I want to get primary key in

```
C:\wamp\www\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-gii\generators\model/default/views/index.php
```

Yii use this code

```
$count = 0;
if (($tableSchema = $generator->getTableSchema()) === false) {
    foreach ($generator->getColumnNames() as $name) {
        if (++$count < 6) {
            echo "            '" . $name . "',\n";
        } else {
            echo "            // '" . $name . "',\n";
        }
    }
} else {
    foreach ($tableSchema->columns as $column) {
        $format = $generator->generateColumnFormat($column);
        if (++$count < 6) {
            echo "            '" . $column->name . ($format === 'text' ? "" : ":" . $format) . "',\n";
        } else {
            echo "            // '" . $column->name . ($format === 'text' ? "" : ":" . $format) . "',\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to get primaryKey before belowing code.

> $generator->getTableSchema()->primaryKey();

but is not working.

Answer (score 2):

That function does not return what you want. It will return the name attribute that may be the primary key or it may not be. If you add a column called "name" in your DB the name of that column will get returned and NOT the primary key.

Furthermore the purpose of that function is to return the name of 1 column. That 1 column may not be the full primary key, it may be part of it, if you have a primary key composed of multiple columns again that function will fail you.

The correct way to get it is

```
$class = $this->modelClass;
$pk = $class::primaryKey();
```

and $pk is an array.

Your answer may solve your problem (and I have used similar things myself in my code), but it does not really answer your question (how to get the primary key).

Answer (score 0):

I find a function from

> C:\wamp\www\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-gii\generators\crud\Generator.php

function is getNameAttribute()

```
 public function getNameAttribute()
{
    foreach ($this->getColumnNames() as $name) {
        if (!strcasecmp($name, 'name') || !strcasecmp($name, 'title')) {
            return $name;
        }
    }
    /* @var $class \yii\db\ActiveRecord */
    $class = $this->modelClass;
    $pk = $class::primaryKey();

    return $pk[0];
}
```

And I call following code successfully in file:

> C:\wamp\www\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-gii\generators\model/default/views/index.php

such as

```
<?= $generator->getNameAttribute(); ?>//id
```

OR shortly

```
<?= $nameAttribute; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$generator->getTableSchema()->primaryKey();
```

is not a method, is a property then would be:

```
$generator->getTableSchema()->primaryKey;
```

this return an array, for get the column name you must access to the first element of array, like

```
$generator->getTableSchema()->primaryKey[0];
```

For other hand, you can make:

```
  foreach ($generator->getTableSchema()->columns as $column) {
    if ($column->isPrimaryKey) {
      // your code
    }
```